# Unable to locate webelement which is wrapped in nested classes

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My task is to locate "quote1" and click on "add" button:

```
<div Class = “binder”
<div class = “books ”
<form style = “book1”
<div class = “pages ” 
<div class = “page1”
<div class = “paragrph”
<div class = “line “     “  quote1”
<div class = “add”  ”             //add button


<div Class = “binder”
<div class = “books ”
<form style = “book1”
<div class = “pages ” 
<div class = “page1”
<div class = “paragrph”
<div class = “line “     “  quote2”
<div class = “add”             (add button)
```

I tried using CSS selector:

```
#binder>books>book1>pages>page1>paragraph>line:contains(quote1)>add
```

it didn't work. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: It is virtually impossible to answer your question without being able to view the page source.

Answer (score 0):

Using xpath:

```
//div[contains(@class,'line') and contains(text(), 'quote1')]//div[@class='add']
```

If there's a specific element, like button or input, add that to the end (/button)

Comment: i tried but it didn't work . "line" class is nested in  6 classes . I thought I have to mention all the classes  prior to 'line class" and i don't know  the syntax for multiple classes .

Comment: if I get the xpath  it looks like below

Comment: //*[@id="content_right"]/div[5]/div[1]/form/div[3]/div[2]/div[19]/div[2]/div/div[1]      note : div[19] is  dynamic element.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selector cannot read the contents of a node; only a node's attributes. This means you cannot use "contains" like you tried. Instead you need to use xpath.

```
//div[contains(@class,'line') and contains(text(),'quote1')]/div[contains(@class,'add')]
```

You don't need to list all the parent nodes so long as you can start the path at a unique point (such as an ID or a unique piece of text).

Comment: the unique point  in this path is "quote1".  I have 32 nodes  with same  class= "line" and each line class has its own quote#. so i was thinking of locating the element by the quote #

Comment: @sunitamatani, yes. Which is what I said. Have you tried the above code, and did it work?

Comment: I tried, It didn't work :(

Comment: @sunitamatani, what error are you getting? How doesn't it work? What are you trying to do with the element you select?

Comment: i am getting an error "element can be located''

Comment: <div class="line">
quote1
</div>
<div class="add">+</div>

<div class="line">
quote2
</div>
<div class="add">+</div>

Comment: I am trying to locate and click on the add button  for quote1 which is  under class line

Comment: OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element:

Comment: The HTML you put here is different than you describe; it is not **nested**, they are siblings and that completely change how things need to work. Please post the _actual and complete_ section of HTML you are working with otherwise you will never get a correct answer. **Under**, as in located on the line of code beneath, means nothing to CSS or XPath. It all has to do with opening and closing tags.

Answer (score 0):

Using the any one of the below xpath will locate the element.First one is a text based xpath and the second one is an attribute based xpath.

```
//div[contains(text(),'quote1')]

//div[contains(@class='quote1')]
```

Comment: <div class="line">
 quote1
</div>

Comment: I was unable to locate quote1  by text based or attribute .

Comment: <div class="line">
quote1
</div>
<div class="add">+</div>

 I need to locate the add button for quote1 which is under class line .
 quote1  is not getting identified as text or an  attribute .

Answer (score 0):

//div[contains(@class,'quote1') and @class='add']

(//div[@class='add'])[1]

The above xpath will locate the first matching "add" button and you can specify the number in the [] based on your match.